# Saving Iphone .caf files on AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, react-native, expo, caf

I'm trying to record and save Audio to AWS S3. I'm able to record and play the newly recorded audio in the App, but when trying to save the following file (using https://github.com/benjreinhart/react-native-aws3), the file turns up empty in S3:

```
const file = { uri: sound, name:${name}.caf, type: "audio/x-caf" };
```

Has anyone found an audio type that works with .caf?

Comment: An incorrect MIME type wouldn't cause the file to be "empty" (0 bytes).  Is the file really empty, or just not usable?